# Stuck on this double integral

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

I need some help trying to solve this integral

$$\int_0^1 \int_0^{1-x^2} x\cos(2y-y^2) \,dy\,dx$$

The closest I got to a solution was

$$\int_0^1 \frac{1}{2x}\sin(-x^4+1) \,dx$$

But I'm not sure how to continue or if there is a different way to do it

Answer (score 3):

Try interchanging the limits to$$\int_0^1 \int_0^{\sqrt{1-y}} xcos(2y-y^2) \,dx\,dy=\int_0^1\frac{1-y}{2}\cos(2y-y^2)dy=\frac{1}{4}\sin(2y-y^2)\big|_0^1=\frac{\sin 1}{4}.$$

Answer (score 2):

Take into account that your integral is equal to$$\int_0^1\int_0^{\sqrt{1-y}}x\cos(2y-y^2)\,\mathrm dx\,\mathrm dy,$$which can be computed as follows:\begin{align}\int_0^1\int_0^{\sqrt{1-y}}x\cos(2y-y^2)\,\mathrm dx\,\mathrm dy&=\int_0^1\frac12(1-y)\cos(2y-y^2)\,\mathrm dy\\&=\left[\frac14\sin(2y-y^2)\right]_{y=0}^{y=1}\\&=\frac{\sin1}4.\end{align}